# Can not set low priority in using pthread_setschedparam() for pthreads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, concurrency, pthreads

I was trying to set a low priority [ priority = 10 ], in Linux using

> **`pthread_setschedparam()`**

However, the accepted values I get from function
**`sched_get_priority_{min|max}()`** is 0-99.

If I give 1, I get priority as -2.
If I give 90, I get priority as -90.
But I want to get priority 10.

Code is given below. Is there a way to assign low priority to a thread.
[ NOTE - I tried also a **setpriority**, but that doesn't work in my case, since I need to assign priorities from the main thread ]

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

void *print_message_function( void *ptr );

main()
{
     pthread_t thread1, thread2;
     const char *message1 = "Thread 1";
     const char *message2 = "Thread 2";
     int  iret1, iret2;

     struct sched_param sch_params;
     //sch_params.sched_priority = 5;
     sch_params.sched_priority = 10; 

    /* Create independent threads each of which will execute function */

     iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message1);
     if(iret1)
     {   
         printf("Error - pthread_create() return code: %d\n",iret1);
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }   
     if(pthread_setschedparam(thread1, SCHED_RR, &sch_params)) {
        printf( "Failed to set thread's priority : %s \n",strerror(errno));
     } else {
        printf( "thread priority is set properly: \n");
     }   

     pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void *print_message_function( void *ptr )
{
     char *message;
     message = (char *) ptr;
     while (1) {
        printf("%s \n", message);
        sleep(1);
     }   
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you observing priority values -2, -90, etc?

Comment: using htop, and checking for process name

Comment: Maybe this example can help https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/attrib-16/index.html

Comment: I suspect that you are being misled by the manner in which scheduling information is being presented to you by `htop`.  I see no particular reason to assume that the "priority" number it presents corresponds exactly to the priority number that you set via `pthread_setschedparam()`.  You should consider instead reading back the priority via `pthread_getschedparam()`.  Having confirmed (I predict) that the priority is read back correctly, then you can look into what `htop` is telling you.

Comment: What is the name of the htop column that contains the values -2, -90, etc?

Comment: Note also that "setting low priority" is relative.  You cannot use `pthread_setscheduleparam()` to set lower priority than normal threads, because non-zero priorities can be assigned only to threads that have real-time scheduling policies (one of which you are indeed assigning).  Even low priority real-time threads have higher scheduling priority than all non-realtime threads.

Comment: @zwol , I am using `PRI` column in htop to determine priority

Comment: @Marichyasana, I would like to set priority after I have started a thrtead. The example points to creating a thread with a priority

Comment: @John Bollinger , the problem here is that the range of value that can be set via `pthread_setscheduleparam` is `0-99` AFAIK. And these values corresponds to `0 to [-99]` . So looks like I can not set a thread to priority `+10` in linux using `pthread_setscheduleparam()` . Is that correct ? Is there any other way to set priority to `+10` in Linux via c ?

Comment: You are focusing too much on specific numbers.  The big picture is as I described in an earlier comment, coming down to the fact that you cannot use `pthread_setschedparam()` to give a thread lower priority than normal, non-realtime threads have.  But a thread *can* make itself `nice()`er, which seems to be what you want.